# disable osk (onscreen virtual keyboard) in windows 7 (or vista) OR customize osk layout

Tags: keyboard

I use windows 7 as host for touchscreen PC in public environment. I would like to prevent the OS being controled by a user. 
With a physical keyboard, you would remove the control and alt keys. But with the built-in on-screen keyboard?

does anybody know how to customize or completely remove the on-screen keyboard (osk) that appears in windows 7 when you touch the left border of a touchscreen ?

I've been trying for hours, including one hour with the help from a MS support tech guy, and we found ... nothing!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to either set permissions on the osk.exe executable so the user is unable to run it or add a path rule to Software Restriction Policies forbidding the execution of osk.exe altogether.

Comment: Thank you very much syneticon-dj. I'll try this tomorrow. Can you just tell me how to "add a path rule to Software Restriction Policies" ? I've never done that. How do you start to do that ?